# Spark: How to convert Epoch days to a Date object

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Spark: 2.4.5 with Scala

I am having a column in my Dataframe which holds the number of days since epoch (1970). I am looking for a way to convert that into a Date Column.

So I am working on writing a function like below:

```
 def from_epochday(epochDays: Column):Column = {
    date_add(to_date(lit("1970-01-01"), "YYYY-MM-DD") , epochDays /* Need to int and not a Column*/)
  }
```

The data Frame will have :

```
df.withColumn("dob", from_epochday(col(epochDays)))
```

The problem is date_add take Int as input and I am not able to figure out how to get the value as Int.

Probably I can do it via UDF function but not trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

A day has `86400` seconds in it. You could multiply this with epoch days to get epoch second and then use `from_unixtime`.

```
scala> java.time.LocalDate.ofEpochDay(1)
res16: java.time.LocalDate = 1970-01-02

scala> java.time.LocalDate.ofEpochDay(2)
res17: java.time.LocalDate = 1970-01-03

scala> val df = Seq(1,2).toDF("days")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [days: int]

scala> df.withColumn("date", from_unixtime(col("days")*86400, "yyyy-MM-dd").cast("date")).show
+----+----------+
|days|      date|
+----+----------+
|   1|1970-01-02|
|   2|1970-01-03|
+----+----------+
```

Comment: have already tried this but this is not working for me. The o/p data is always 1 day less than actual

Comment: This replicates the exact behaviour of LocalDate.ofEpochDay. However if you want different behaviour you could add/subtract 1 to the epochDay before multiplying with 86400.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way that you can do it.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, 18508),

    ],
    schema=StructType(
        [
            StructField('Id', StringType(), True),
            StructField('Epoch_days', LongType(), True)
        ]
    )
)

df.withColumn(
    'date',
    (col('Epoch_days')*86400).cast('timestamp') 
).show(truncate=False)

#+---+----------+-------------------+
#|Id |Epoch_days|date               |
#+---+----------+-------------------+
#|1  |18508     |2020-09-03 00:00:00|
#+---+----------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 val df = Seq(1).toDF("seq").select(
    from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(),"MM-dd-yyyy").as("date_1"),
    from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(),"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss").as("date_2"),
     from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(),"yyyy-MM-dd").as("date_3")
   ).show(false)
```

- https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-epoch-time-to-timestamp-date/

Comment: from_unixtime() //Converts the number of seconds from unix epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC) to a string. What I have is epoch days not seconds. So this function will lead to incorrect value

Comment: I am looking for something LocalDate ofEpochDay(long epochDay) from Java